# ArcMap polygon labelings

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, python-parser

I have a challenge with advanced labels of polygons in ArcMap 10.1. I wish to make the label take the longest direction(either curved, horizontal, vertical or diagonal) inside the polygon.

The python code I used is below. I need a modified python code to specify and orient the labels along the longest direction of an ArcMap polygon.

```
def FindLabel([BLOCK], [CLONE], [PLANTED_DATE], [Area]):
 
    labels1=' '
    if [CLONE] is not None:
        labels1 =("<CLR red='150'><FNT size = '6.7'>" + [CLONE] + "</FNT></CLR>")

    labels2=' '
    if [PLANTED_DATE] is not None:
        labels2 = ("<CLR blue='255'><FNT size = '6'>" + [PLANTED_DATE] + "</FNT></CLR>")

    labels3=' '
    if [Area] is not None and [Area] !=0:
        labels3 = ("<CLR red='255'><FNT size = '5.5'>" + [Area] + "</FNT></CLR>")
        
    lab =  labels1 + " " + labels2 + " " + labels3
    return lab
```

Comment: "label1 - if - label2"  "label3 - if - label2" "label4 - if - label3". The sequence is intentional or is there a mistake? I mean "1 then 2" 3 then 2" "4 then 3". And you don't use `label4`.

Comment: I think you need to be labelling using the [maplex engine](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/what-is-maplex-.htm) to have labels that orientate with the geometry? Can't remember if this was available in arcmap 10.1 as that is such an old piece of software.

Comment: Maplex was available that long ago, but it may have been an extra-cost extension then. It won't perfectly solve the OP's problem, but could be an 80 percent or better solution.

Comment: As discussed above, do you have Malplex?  If so, here is a link for how to spread the labels through a polygon for ArcGIS 10.3.  I didn't see a link for 10.1  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/spreading-the-words-of-a-label-inside-a-polygon.htm.

Comment: Thanks all, I have used the maplex engine and yet to be satisfied with it the result I got. @Kadir Sahbaz I have edited the codes to reflect what I used.